# create multiple arrays on different elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to set a function in my application which allows the user to click on a button and then click the submit button which displays an image, but I want the buttons to hold more than one image and randomly select an image from the array.

How can I do this?

```js
    <div id='prefPage'>

    <header id='header2pref'>

    <div id='title2pref'>PREFERENCES</div>
    
    </header>

    <div id='body'>
    <div id='leftAlign'>
    <div id="foodpicloc">



    </div>
           
           
         
    </div><button id='myBtn2'>SET PREFRENCES</button>


      
    <div id='rightAlignPref'>

    <div id=fixed>

    <div>
    
    <button id="button1">BURGER</button>
    <button id="button2">HOTDOG</button>

    </div>
                
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    </div>



var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

var preference = document.getElementById("preference");
var foodpic = document.getElementById("foodpiclocation");
var foodpic;

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  foodpicurl = 'burger.svg';
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  foodpicurl = 'hotdog.svg';
});

preference.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var foodpic = document.createElement('img');
  foodpic.src = foodpicurl;

  foodpiclocation.innerHTML = '';
  foodpiclocation.appendChild(foodpic);
});
```

Comment: if you can align your HTML code that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution using vanilla Javascript. NOTE: I suggest you add this to your HTML code `<div id="foodpicloc"><img id="foodpic"></div>` in your HTML first. Changing the image's src is quicker and cleaner than appending a new image element everytime the image changes.

**Define**

```
function mapClickToImage(imageSelector, updateBtnSelector, btnSectorToImageSrcMapping) {

  var currentImageSrc = null;
  var imageElement = document.querySelector(imageSelector);
  for (var btnSelector in btnSectorToImageSrcMapping) {

    var buttonElement = document.querySelector(btnSelector);
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentImageSrc = btnSectorToImageSrcMapping[btnSelector];
  });

  var updateButtonElement = document.querySelector(updateBtnSelector);
  updateButtonElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (currentImageSrc) {
      imageElement.src = currentImageSrc;
    }
  });
}
```

**Usage**

```
mapClickToImage('#foodpic', '#preference', {
  '#button1': 'burger.svg',
  '#button2': 'hotdog.svg'
});
```